# Can no longer connect to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

**The setup:**

- Virtual machine hosting MongoDB
- Virtual machine running Ubuntu
- Local Machine Running Windows

**The scenario:**

Code that previously worked with no issue is no longer working. The code takes order data from a source and then pushes that data to our MongoDB.

- Using MongoDB compass on the **Local machine** has no trouble connecting.
- Running `sudo systemctl status mongod` on the **Virtual machine hosting MongoDB** shows that all systems are go.
- The code that is running on **Virtual machine running Ubuntu** causing issue:

```
try {    
    await client.connect(); // Connect to mongo
    const database = client.db("linndash"); // Connect to  database
    const collection = database.collection("open-orders"); // Connect to collection
    const cursor = collection.find(); // Find all the documents from mongo
    if ((await cursor.count()) === 0) {
      console.log("No documents found!");
    }
    mongoOrders = [];
    await cursor.forEach((c) => {
      mongoOrders.push(c.OrderId);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  } finally {
    return mongoOrders;
  }
```

**The ouput**

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [10.0.0.111:27017] on 
first connect [Error: connect EADDRNOTAVAIL 10.0.0.111:27017 - Local (10.0.0.110:0)
    at internalConnect (net.js:921:16)
    at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (internal/async_hooks.js:429:12)
    at net.js:1009:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError'
}]
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong here, I can connect to mongo without issue from my local windows machine, the machine running MongoDB isn't having an issue. The issue seems to be with the Ubuntu machine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As silly as it seems, logging into the MongoDB machine and running `sudo service mongod restart` worked.

I was certain that the issue was on the Ubuntu machine, but no!